# A break in the debugger session because a user paused the session in windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, web-services, xaml

When I run my program I get an error on this line: `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
{
 if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)  global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Brea();
};
#endif
```

And also it show error message "A break in the debugger session because a user paused the session".

Does anybody know how to fix this?